# How to test FileReader wrapped inside promise?

Tags: testing, promise, mocking, jestjs, filereader

Current code:

```
export const readFilePromise = file => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = error => {
      reject(error);
    };
  });
};
```

I am able to test the onload method

```
it('readFilePromise method', async () => {
    const fileContentsEncodedInHex = [
      '\x45\x6e\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x49\x6e\x48\x65\x78\x42\x65\x63\x61\x75\x73\x65\x42\x69\x6e\x61\x72\x79\x46\x69\x6c\x65\x73\x43\x6f\x6e\x74\x61\x69\x6e\x55\x6e\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x61\x62\x6c\x65\x43\x68\x61\x72\x61\x63\x74\x65\x72\x73'
    ];
    const blob = new Blob(fileContentsEncodedInHex);
    const result = readFilePromise(blob);
    const output = await result;
    const expectedOutput =
      'data:;base64,RW5jb2RlSW5IZXhCZWNhdXNlQmluYXJ5RmlsZXNDb250YWluVW5wcmludGFibGVDaGFyYWN0ZXJz';
    expect(output).toEqual(expectedOutput);
  });
```

I wonder how do I test the `onerror`?

Answer (score 0):

If you had something like below because of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/error)

```
reader.onerror = () => {
  reject(reader.error);
};
```

Then the below should work.

Just know beforehand error message for passing empty file or nothing. I just wanted to create a scenario

```
 describe('Error Case', () => {
        it('should return error message for empty file', () => {
              const result = readFilePromise();
               const n = () => {};
               return result.then(n, (errorMessage) => {
                expect('your error message here').to.equal(errorMessage);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi, the current issue is that reader.readAsDataURL(file), fail before reaching reader.onerror. The error is not passing Blob to readAsDataURL

Comment: Hi, I answered based on your original question about how to test `onerror` . It is difficult to tell why `reader.readAsDataURL(file)`  is failing based on info provided.

Comment: Getting the same failed error before onerror.

`Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`